# Sum the related values from a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list

Here are the values printing from a record, I need to sum up the 1st number when based on the second number.
If the first second numbers are same, the first number needes to be added.

```
record = [[2, 3], [3, 3], [5, 4], [1, 4]]

Expected output = [5, 3], [6, 4]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first sort, then `itertools.groupby` the second value.

```
import itertools
import operator

records = [[2, 3], [3, 3], [5, 4], [1, 4]]
records.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
groups = itertools.groupby(records, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
# groups is now a generator that produces the values:
#   (3, [[2, 3], [3, 3]])
#   (4, [[5, 4], [1, 4]])
```

Then produce a list over the results:

```
result = [[sum(record[0] for record in records), grpname] for grpname, records in groups]
```

Comment: If you're only interested in sum, Counter is easier to use than groupby.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). It will be easy to use and you won't need to sort anything:

```
from collections import Counter
record = [[2, 3], [3, 3], [5, 4], [1, 4]]
sums = Counter()
for (value, index) in record:
    sums[index] += value
sums
# Counter({3: 5, 4: 6})
```

It shouldn't be too hard to convert the Counter values to the desired output.

Comment: Isn't this just `collections.defaultdict(int)`? We're not getting any of the cool `Counter` behavior here.

Comment: That said -- it should still be significantly faster than my sort -> groupby approach :)

Comment: @AdamSmith: I don't think there's any Counter constructor which works directly with OP's data format. One possibility would be `Counter(k for (v, k) in record for _ in range(v))` but it isn't readable or efficient IMHO.

Comment: Nice coding@EricDuminil

Answer (score 1):

Algorithm:
1. Sort List according to the second element in the inner list.
2. Merge consecutive element heaving the same value of the second element.

```
record = [[1,5],[2, 3], [2,5] , [3, 3], [5, 4], [1, 4]]
record.sort(key=lambda x: x[1]) #sorting record according to second value in inner list
length=len(record)
newRecord=[record[0].copy()] #initating newRecording with first value from record
for i in range(1,length):
    if newRecord[-1][1]==record[i][1]:
        #if value of second element is equal than this will execute
        newRecord[-1][0]+=record[i][0]
    else:
        #if value of second element is not equal than this will execute
        newRecord.append(record[i])

print(newRecord)
```

Hope this help.